# Help with first order non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I've been trying to solve this one for a while, but I still can't make it. Here's the problem.

I have a $f_1(t;\rho,\nu)$ that for $t\to\infty$ and for $\rho>\nu$ goes as $f_1\sim t^{\nu/\rho}.$

Saying that, the problem is with a second function $f_2(t, \rho\, \nu)$ which obeys the equation:

$\frac{df_2(t)}{dt}=\frac{\nu f_2(t) + (\nu+1)f_1(t)}{\rho t + (\nu+1)[f_1(t)+f_2(t)]}$

with $\rho,\nu\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $f_2(t)>0$ (and increasing).

I am interested in the long term behavior as for $f_1$. I know (from simulations) that for $t\to\infty$ it behaves similarly to $f_1$, but with a different exponent. I've tried to plug in the $f_1$ written above (assuming $\rho>\nu)$ and also to force $f_2(t)\sim ct^\alpha$ as a solution, ultimately looking for an expression for $\alpha$ as a function of the other parameters, but I only arrived to contradict myself.

I've also tried on Mathematica with initial conditions $f_2(0)=0$ but without succeeding.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If this is a differential equation, you don't want $t \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: OK thanks Robert. I put it there because in the original process it's defined in discrete times, but here I totally agree that it doesn't make sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it might have the same exponent, but logarithmic terms. Rather than try to solve the differential equation for $f_2(t)$, I tried plugging in a form for $f_2(t)$ and solving for $f_1(t)$.  I found that 
$$ f_2(t) = \frac{\nu + 1}{\rho} \log(t)\; t^{\nu/\rho} $$
is a solution with
$$ f_1(t) = {\frac {1}{\rho} \left( {t}^{{\frac {\nu+
\rho}{\rho}}}{\rho}^{3}+\ln  \left( t \right) {t}^{2\,{\frac {\nu}{
\rho}}} \left( \nu+1 \right) ^{2} \left( \ln  \left( t \right) \nu+
\rho \right)  \right)  \left( - \left( \nu+1 \right)  \left( \ln 
 \left( t \right) \nu+\rho \right) {t}^{{\frac {\nu}{\rho}}}+{\rho}^{2
}t \right) ^{-1}} \sim t^{\nu/\rho}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot robert for the hint!
So, just to be sure, you plugged a $f_2(t)=ct^\alpha$ into the diff. equation and the second Eq. you wrote is the solution you got? I'm missing the bit where you derive then the $f_2(t)$

Comment: No, I plugged in $f_2(t) = c \log(t) t^{\nu/\rho}$ and solved for $f_1(t)$, then found what $c$ was needed for $f_1(t) \sim t^{\nu/\rho}$.